# Including .erb in Facebook <meta> tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I've been having a lot of trouble getting Facebook to recognize `<meta>` tags that contain `.erb`. Here's an example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Projects <%= @company.name.present? ? ('with ' + @company.name) : '' %>" />
```

Here's a few details:

1. The page source shows the meta title fully and as I would expect.
2. I put `logger debug @company.name` right above the meta tag and I'm seeing the expected result.
3. On FB, all I see is "Projects".

Do you know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use ' ' instead of " " ; ex:

```
   <meta property="og:description" content='<%= @job_details.description %>' />
```

This should not truncate the string

Comment: Do you know why the quotes make a difference Alessio?

Comment: For sure one of the differences is that with the double quotes you can use the interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your ruby inclusion into a string is wrong.

```
"Projects <%= @company.name.present? ? ('with ' + @company.name) : '' %>"
--> "Projects <%= @company.name.present? ? ('with ' + @company.name) : '' %>"

<%= "Projects #{ @company.name.present? ? ('with ' + @company.name) : '' }" %>
--> "Projects with Apple"

<%= "Projects " + @company.name.present? ? ('with ' + @company.name) : '' %>
--> "Projects with Apple"
```

Choose one of the two last solutions to fix your issue !

Comment: That's not it Alexandre. The second, when inserted into an html string, shows as-is, and the third is just ignored by FB. For some reason, it seems to be avoiding everything generated by .erb.

Comment: Oh, right. My second syntax is wrong too (I have edited it now). Can you insert ruby code in an other part of the file ?

Comment: Absolutely - the ruby works fine everywhere, except apparently when in this kind of tag (or perhaps somehow it is ignored by Facebook's .js, though that doesn't make much sense to me either).